# php custum sql return value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a data table in which I return value from sql query. Now there is one problem. I want to return not actual sql value but custum parameter which matches with sql value db. For example, I have a state value which is in sql database described as D - done, N - new, P - in progress. So in datable table I want to see these values instead of these three letters.  My php code fragment:

```
        $data = "";
        $array = db_get_task();
        if ($array != null) 
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
            {
                $data .= '<tr>
                    <td>' . $array[$i]['task'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $array[$i]['id'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $array[$i]['cust'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $array[$i]['City'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $array[$i]['STATE'] . '</td>   //this line returns D, N or P values
                    <td>' . $array[$i]['date'] . '</td>
                    </tr>';
            }
        }
```

By the way. In database these letters use varchar type

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $data = "";

 $values = array('D' => 'done', 'N' => 'new', 'P' => 'in progress');

 $array = db_get_task();

    if ($array != null) 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
        {
            $data .= '<tr>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['task'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['id'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['cust'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['City'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $values[$array[$i]['STATE']] . '</td>   //this line returns done, new or in progress values
                <td>' . $array[$i]['date'] . '</td>
                </tr>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: If its working, kindly hesitate to accept the answer.

Comment: I am new user here, so I am able to answer this question after 8 hours only

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
$states = array('D' => 'done', 'N' => 'new', 'P' => 'in progress');

$data = "";
$array = db_get_task();
if ($array != null) 
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {
        $data .= '<tr>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['task'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['id'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['cust'] . '</td>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['City'] . '</td>
                <td>' . if(array_key_exists($array[$i]['STATE'], $states) { $states[$array[$i]['STATE']]; }. '</td>
                <td>' . $array[$i]['date'] . '</td>
                </tr>';
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

Create a **`custom associative array`** for all the **`states`**. The if the **`value`** (viz. D, N, P) exists as the **`key`** in the `array`, get the **`value`**.